# "Missing { inserted" when using own macro in formula

Tags: math-mode, macros, errors, amsmath

When using following code I get a few errors but the output is exactly how I want it to be, so I'm not sure why there are errors then:

```
\newcommand{\desc}[2]{\underbrace{#1}_\substack{#2}}
${\desc{R-H}{Alkan}} + {\desc{X_2}{Halogen}} \xrightarrow{H_\nu + UV-Bestrahlung} {\desc{R-X}{Halogenalkan}} + {\desc{H-X}{Halogenwasserstoff}}$
```

Thats how it looks like and how it should look like:

[image: Output]

**Errors I get:**

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \vcenter 
l.250 ${{\desc{R-H}{Alkan}} + {\desc{X_2}{Halogen}
                                                  } \xrightarrow{H_\nu + UV-...
A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
(If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \vcenter 
l.250 ...UV-Bestrahlung} {\desc{R-X}{Halogenalkan}
                                                  } + {\desc{H-X}{Halogenwas...
A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
(If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \vcenter 
l.250 ...alkan}} + {\desc{H-X}{Halogenwasserstoff}
                                                  }}$
A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
(If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.250 ...an}} + {\desc{H-X}{Halogenwasserstoff}}}$

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
```

Comment: `\newcommand{\desc}[2]{\underbrace{#1}_{\substack{#2}}}` (note the additional braces around `\substack{#2}`.

Comment: In addition to what @GustavoMezzetti said, I would also replace `\substack` with `\text`, assuming that second argument is always text, as in your example. You also want `\text{UV-bestrahlung}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\substack` is an expandable token, hence you need to wrap it up in braces to make it a subscript.  Also, I don’t think you need to make each term of your reaction a subformula, by enclosing it in braces.  **Edit:** I had overlooked the `\text` issue, but Torbjørn T. drew my attention to it.  **Second edit:** It looks like today I‘m more absentminded than usual: thanks to @lblb, too, for remarking that there is another piece of text that should be wrapped by `\text`!

Hence I propose the following fix:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\desc}[2]{\underbrace{#1}_{\text{#2}}}



\begin{document}

Abc $\desc{R-H}{Alkan} + \desc{X_2}{Halogen}
\xrightarrow{H_\nu + \text{UV-Bestrahlung}}
\desc{R-X}{Halogenalkan} + \desc{H-X}{Halogenwasserstoff}$ def.

\end{document}
```

Comment: " + UV-Bestrahlung" should be also made text. Typesetting text segments without such treatment is bad style, LaTeX then treats each letter as a variable, resulting in italic shape and bad kerning. I would also propose to make the atom symbols upright, they have a fixed meaning.

Comment: @lblb: Thanks again for your suggestions.  I cannot judge about the semantics of the formula, so I’m not able to tell whether R, H, and X should be upright or no: I just addressed the error concerning the (La)TeX syntax.

Comment: Of course. I just hope Martin Niederl considers it.